# ActionScript 3 as a console app?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is it possible to have actionscript 3 as a console app? I want to play around with the language and do basic things like hello world and inheritances or file IO if thats allowed. Is there a REPL or a compiler (that will allow me to write a console app) for actionscript 3?

Comment: Maybe [wonderfl](http://wonderfl.net/)?

Comment: @Cameron: Excellent suggestion. I tried to do inheritance for fun and i couldn't have more than one 'visible' (top leveled?) class and i couldn't use another package or nest packages or classes. How the heck am i suppose to do anything interesting with types/classes!?

Comment: @ValentinSimonov: It doesn't let me? http://wonderfl.net/c/ndEC/ "HelloFlag.as(18): col: 18 Error: Classes must not be nested."

Answer (score 3):

If you're serious about command line as3 you should have a look at redtamarin, based off the Mozilla Tamarin project:

http://code.google.com/p/redtamarin/

Though I think the complexity of building the tools might defeat the purpose of a "hello world" situation? Depends if you're looking for proper command line tools or just experimentation.