# How to inject ActionScript CuePoints into FLV file programmatically

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, actionscript

I am working on a project currently and I would like to be able to inject ActionScript CuePoints into an input video file. I wish to inject these every 1 second and they inject an Object that shall have roughly 11 fields (not sure if thats the terminology used or not? I'm a Java bloke)

However my issues are these, I am unfamiliar with AS3 and Flash and am unsure as to how to take an MP4 file as input with an XML file full of the data I will organise into objects, and then output an FLV.

As this is a part of a larger system, I am also unaware of how to execute the AS3 program from the command line i.e $console: flash injector.as Video.mp4 Info.xml

The reason I wish to inject these cuepoints is so that upon playback, I want to access the data at each cuepoint as the video file is playing so I can use the data during video playback.

I am sure this is not a particularly complex task however my inexperience in the flash and AS3 environment is stumping me for the moment.

So far the useful documentation I have found as been:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#addASCuePoint%28%29

and

[Is it possible to create a 'command line' swf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056056/is-it-possible-to-create-a-command-line-swf)

However I am somewhat stumped as to how best to proceed. Any help on the matter is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your question how to create a f4v with cuepoints from an mp4 file?
You can do that using the Adobe Media Encoder, which is included when you install Flash.
The Media Encoder has a dialog box where you can manually add cuepoints which will be included when you export an f4v or flv file.

If you need to add tons of cuepoints it's better to do that using actionscript, according to the example you already found:

```
// not tested, but should be something like this
for(var i = 0;i<100;i++) {
    player.addASCuePoint({time:i,name:"test"+i, type:"actionscript"});
}

// then, you can start listening for the cuepoints when the movie is playing:
player.addEventListener(MetadataEvent.CUE_POINT, cue_listener); 
function cp_listener(eventObject:MetadataEvent):void { 
    trace("Elapsed time in seconds: " + player.playheadTime); 
    trace("Cue point name is: " + eventObject.info.name); 
    trace("Cue point type is: " + eventObject.info.type); 
}
```

Comment: Apologies hadn't seen your response, I will give it a whirl. Thanks.